# Decode JSON with square brackets

Tags: php, json, echo

I have tried to decode this json,but no luck,these square brackets are making me confused
any help would be appreciated,here is my json

```
[{"location":[{"building":["Default Building"],"name":"Default Location"}],"name":"Default Organization"}]
```

Thank you

Comment: Seems to be valid JSON. So what is your problem?

Comment: `$str = '[{"location":[{"building":["Default Building"],"name":"Default Location"}],"name":"Default Organization"}]';
print_r(json_decode($str));` It is valid JSON and square brackets means Array: http://www.json.org/

Comment: checked here. Its valid, Why you are confused?

Comment: I think you are facing problem here  "building": [
                    "Default Building"
                ],

Comment: sir,i would like to take the value of each key separately ,how can i do that i dont want var_export

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
var_export( json_decode( '[{"location":[{"building":["Default Building"],"name":"Default Location"}],"name":"Default Organization"}]' )  );
```

`json_decode` return array or `object` . you can print it with `var_export` not `echo`

and you can access to values :

```
$items = json_decode('[{"location":[{"building":["Default Building"],"name":"Default Location"}],"name":"Default Organization"}]');

foreach( $items as $each ){
  echo $each->location[0]->building[0];
  echo '<hr />';
  echo $each->location[0]->name;
  echo '<hr />';
  echo $each->name; // default organization
}
```

Comment: Thank you all,@ Alireza41,how can i retrieve the value default organisation

Answer (score 1):

Your json is valid , might be you are facing problem while accessing the objects inside the array.

print_r is always a good friend to understand array structure . try this

```
    $json = '[{"location":[{"building":["Default Building"],"name":"Default Location"}],"name":"Default Organization"}]';
$decoded = json_decode($json);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($decoded);

$location = $decoded[0]->location;
$building = $location[0]->building[0];
$name = $location[0]->name;
```

Object at place 0 will only return the first item , if your array has multiple values then use foreach

Answer (score 0):

Seems its a valid JSON.

```
$my_json = '[{"location":[{"building":["Default Building"],"name":"Default Location"}],"name":"Default Organization"}]';
$my_data = json_decode($my_json);
print_r($my_data);
```

// Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [location] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [building] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Default Building
                                )

                            [name] => Default Location
                        )

                )

            [name] => Default Organization
        )

)
```

Answer (score -1):

For this case, I prefer to add curly brackets before and after the string. It allows me then to use `json_decode($json, true);` which is my favorite way to interact with json variables.

```
  $my_json = '[{"location":[{"building":["Default Building"],"name":"Default Location"}],"name":"Default Organization"}]';
  $json = json_decode('{ "data":'.$my_json.'}', true);
  $my_data = $json['data'][0];
  print_r($my_data['location']);
  echo $my_data['location'][0]['building'][0];
```